# How to avoid duplicate records insert into Table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that inserts records of patients and its bill details on monthly basis. Lets say table "Paitent_Details". On first of every month certain records are inserted for current month. In next month, I want only those month records inserted and not all the records.

Currently I have written one SP to fetch the results, which then store the records in temp table variable, which then insert records into the Patient_Details table.

For example, for sep 2019, I inserted 125 records for Sep. For Oct 2019, I wanted to inserted 100 records, but it ran sep 125 records before inserting 100 records for Oct 2019. Hence ideally, the total counts of records should be 225 (125+100) while the records actually is 350 (125+125+100)

I want to setup a logic to check if Sep-2019 data is inserted, if so to ignore that and to insert only Oct 2019 records.

Comment: As long as you have a PK. you can do a merge or Upsert (Update + insert). Check here http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-merge/

Comment: It would be _much_ easier to answer your question with some sample data, with expected results and a schema definition.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza be cautious with `MERGE`, there are [a few issues with it](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)

Comment: Maybe a `where` clause that makes sure the month/year of the data inserted is equal to the previous month/year from the current date.  You'll use `month()`, `year()`, `getdate()` and `dateadd()`.  Look up those things, try to write a query, and come back with example data and your query so we can actually help you.

Comment: You have more than enough rep around here to know that you need to provide some details with your questions so others can help you. [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try using a left outer join to check for the existence of the record to keep your insert idempotent:

```
INSERT INTO b (Patient_id, DOS, CPT, DetailId)
SELECT a.Patient_Id, a.DOS, a.CPT, a.DetailId
FROM SourceTable_a a
LEFT OUTER JOIN DestinationTable_b b ON b.DetailId = a.DetailId
WHERE b.DetailId IS NULL
```